# Selenium handling browser windows in loop

Tags: java, loops, selenium, iterator

So i have this code which makes current url parent window and new one which i open by doing tasks child window. The problem is that this code does task 1 then closes child window but when it goes to for() loop it opens another window but dont focus it throws error no such window.

```
String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String>s1=driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> I1= s1.iterator();

while(I1.hasNext()){
  String child_window=I1.next();
  if(!parent.equals(child_window))
    {
    driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
    //do task number 1
    driver.close();
for(int x = 1; x < 9000; x = x + 1) {
  driver.switchTo().window(parent);
  //opens another window
  driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
  //do task 2
  driver.close();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz well it closes my child window ... goes back to parent and opens another child thats what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

In the line `driver.switchTo().window(child_window);` you are using the `WindowHandle` of the first window, window that you closed and is no longer available, hence the `NoSuchWindowException`.

You need to get the window handle for the new window every time you open one. You can create a method for switching windows

```
private void switchToWindow(String parentHandle) {
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String windowHandle : windowHandles) {
        if (!parentHandle.equals(windowHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the code will look like this

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

switchToWindow(parentHandle);
//do task number 1
driver.close();

for(int x = 1 ; x < 9000 ; x += 1) {
    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
    //opens another window
    switchToWindow(parentHandle);
    //do task 2
    driver.close();
}
```